# Minor tooltip bug re answer deletion

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, deleted-answers

I just deleted an answer I wrote because it turned out I misunderstood what the OP was trying to ask.  Afterwards, I moused over the "**undelete**" link for no particular reason and noticed that its tooltip remained "vote to remove this post."  When I closed the tab and reloaded the question, the tooltip changed to the correct one, "vote to restore this post."

I know, it's *really* minor, but I figured there's no harm in reporting it.

Answer (score -1):

What about the emotional harm to me, in having to read this? :)

Comment: How many times a week do you toy with the idea of adding a `status-don't-care` tag?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred

Comment: If I may paraphrase a wise man: if this post does you emotional harm, "then I humbly suggest you're overthinking this."