# The tooltip for undelete is still "vote to remove this post"

Tags: bug, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minor tooltip bug re answer deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/minor-tooltip-bug-re-answer-deletion)

(It's not much of a concern since the questions vanish anyway, after a refresh.)

Comment: This is a minor bug on all SO sites.

Comment: Careful... [you could hurt Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/minor-tooltip-bug-re-answer-deletion), talking like that.

Comment: @Pop: I don't think this time he even bothered to read it, then... Your bug-report is more complete, since I thought this only applied to area 51