# Rules for deleting my own answers

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, self-delete

I've noticed that, sometimes, when a user answers a question and the answer is not received well, the answer disappears.

When I try and click the `delete` link below one of my own answers, it asks if I want to vote to delete my answer.

When can users delete their own answers, and when can they only vote to delete them?

Comment: I noted a similar behavior a while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/minor-tooltip-bug-re-answer-deletion

Comment: @Popular This link refers to a thread about the tooltip for the undelete button, and is not directly related to my question.

Comment: the same logic applies to undelete as delete. Except for mods and the post owner it takes multiple votes to change the state of the post.

Comment: @ChrisF Okay. FWIW, the link above is really only about the tooltip not being updated after the answer had been deleted. Now I wonder if the incorrect wording is intentional to discourage deleting your own answers.

Comment: Should this be a feature request/bug report?  If authors can delete their own answers, the hover text shouldn't say "vote to delete" should it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's misleading text. It says vote, but as the author, your one vote is enough to make the deletion happen.

Comment: retag as bug then, perhaps?  or at least feature-request?

Comment: If that's the case, then, yes, it is misleading.